# std::cin issues? What is going on here?? std in vs hard coded value

Tags: c++, stdin

Afternoon all, So i am working on the rod cutting problem. Anyone know why this code works when n is hard coded to 7 or some other number in main, but when I grab n via std:cin it does not work and gives all the wrong output... What is going on here?
Here is output from Setting in main int n = 7
18
1 6 -1
While using std in to get n = 7 i get this:
35
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1
Price list is the same in both instances....
1
5
8
9
10
17
17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int A = 1000;
int p[A];
int r[A], s[A];
void init() {
    p[0] = 0;
    p[1] = 1;
    p[2] = 5;
    p[3] = 8;
    p[4] = 9;
    p[5] = 10;
    p[6] = 17;
    p[7] = 17;
    p[8] = 20;
    p[9] = 24;
    p[10] = 30;
    }

int extendedButtomUpCutRod(int n) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
        int q = -2145631872;
        for (int i = 1; i <= j; ++i)
            if (q < p[i] + r[j - i]) {
                q = p[i] + r[j - i];
                s[j] = i;
            }
         r[j] = q;


    }
    return r[n];
}

// prins the extended method's output
void printCutRodSoln(int n) {
    do
        cout << s[n] << " ";
    while ((n -= s[n]) > 0);
}

int main(){
    init();
    r[0] = 0;
    //int n = 7; //works when this is used.
    int n;
    std::cin >> n; //doesnt work when this is used?


    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        std::cin >> p[i];
    }
    cout << extendedButtomUpCutRod(n) << endl;
    printCutRodSoln(n);
    std::cout << "-1"<< std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine testing it myself, what about the output is unexpected?

Comment: What is the rod cutting problem? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: When I run your program as written and use the inputs you supplied, it hangs waiting for an additional input. This  is because of the  `<=` which should just be `<` in the `for` loop in `main()`.

Comment: Your program expects 8 numbers but you are giving it only 7.

Comment: Changed a few things... that were wrong.  it only runs fine when n is hard coded. when i remove n= 7  us the comented line below it fails.,

Comment: currently only works when i set   //int n = 7; //works when this is used.
    int n;
    std::cin >> n; //doesnt work when this is used?

Answer (score 0):

Comments helped but here was the exact line. that needed changing...
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++),
i = 1  fixed it in all test cases.
Price list was off .